# Why the 'toPromise()' doesn't work for me when

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, es6-promise

I explain my problem with the code example

I have the following service:

```
@Injectable()
export class PartidoProvider extends MyFirestoreProvider<Partido> {

 constructor(  public http: HttpClient,
               public firestore: AngularFirestore) {      
    super('partidos', http, firestore);        
  }

 buscarPartido ( jugador1: Jugador, jugador2: Jugador ) : Observable<Partido[]> {
    let partidoGanaJugador1: Partido = new Partido();
    let partidoPierdeJugador1: Partido = new Partido();

    partidoGanaJugador1.jugadorGanador = jugador1.idDoc;
    partidoGanaJugador1.jugadorPerdedor = jugador2.idDoc;

    partidoPierdeJugador1.jugadorGanador = jugador2.idDoc;
    partidoPierdeJugador1.jugadorPerdedor = jugador1.idDoc;

    return Observable.zip(  this.get(partidoGanaJugador1), 
                        this.get(partidoPierdeJugador1), 
                        (listaGanados, listaPerdidos) => {                                  
                              return listaGanados.concat(listaPerdidos);
    });    
}
```

From a component I need to invoke the service converted to a promise to later use await to wait for the data to return in order to manage the registration in another entity.

Next I show the code of tests of the calls to the service:

```
  async enviarResultado(){
    let rival: Jugador;
    let jugador: Jugador = this.authProvider.jugador;
    let nombreRival: string;
    let partido: Partido;
   // Obtener partido del calendario para añadirle el resultado    
    nombreRival = this.myForm.controls['rival'].value;        
    rival = this.rivales.find( rival => rival.nombre == nombreRival);    

    // THIS WORKS
    const sample = val => Observable.of(val).delay(5000);
    const example = sample('First Example').toPromise().then(result => {
     console.log('From Promise:', result);
          });

    // THIS WORKS
    this.partidoProvider.buscarPartido(jugador, rival).subscribe(
      resultado => {
        console.log("El subscribe ha devuelto datos");
        console.log(resultado);          
      },
      error => {
        console.error("Se ha producido un error al intentar buscar el partido para modificar el resultado")
      }
  );

   // THIS DOESN'T WORK only 1 appears in the debug console (console.log ("1"))
   console.log("1"); 
   this.partidoProvider.buscarPartido(jugador, rival).toPromise()
   .then( lista => {
     console.log("2");
     console.log("Promesa entra");
     console.log("data:" + lista);                      
     if ( lista && lista.length > 0){
       partido = lista[0]
     }
   })
   .catch( error => {
     console.log("2");
     console.error("Se ha producido un error al intentar buscar el partido para modificar el resultado")
    });
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When using `toPromise()` you need to be sure that the source Observables completes.

Observables can emit multiple values so `toPromise()` can't know what is the last value and when it should resolve the Promise it returns.

So my guess is that one of the source Observables created with `this.get(...)` never completes. Maybe you want to use something like this `Observable.zip(...).take(1)`.

Comment: In the code you can see how the observable is completed. The same function is called without "toPromise ()" and returns the correct data.

Comment: Your code doesn't show where either of the Observables complete. Using `.subscribe(v => ...)` will handle only `next` notifications, not the complete notification. Try using `.subscribe(v => ..., undefined, () => console.log('completed'))` and see that it never prints `"completed"` into console.

Comment: You're right. I don't see the "completed". Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 1):

> The toPromise function is actually a bit tricky, as it’s not really an
>   “operator”, rather it’s an RxJS-specific means of subscribing to an
>   Observable and wrap it in a promise. The promise will resolve to the
>   last emitted value of the Observable once the Observable completes.

https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875

Comment: In the code you can see how the observable is completed. The same function is called without "toPromise ()" and returns the correct data.